# How to read PTS/SCR in UVC payload header?

Tags: windows, directshow, uvc

Currently I can use DirectShow to capture uvc frame, then I need PTS to sync the frame with something else.

Of course, I can use libusb-win32 or WinUsb driver and libusb to capture the raw data to get this information, but in this way, I can't use Windows default uvc driver and DirectShow would not work anymore.

Does DirectShow or other library provide any way to access the payload header?